# Google Maps API Not Loading On iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-maps, ipad

I have a webpage that uses the Google Maps API to load a custom map. The map works on Windows and Mac in all major browsers, however it does not work on an iPad. I have tested it on Safari Mobile and Chrome Mobile and the same issue is happening. Nothing shows up and I get the following error in the console:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. 
You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “maps.gstatic.com” 
which could put your confidential information at risk. (main.js, line 0)
```

Any help on what this means would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue was that we were using the HTTP protocol. Using HTTPS protocol when issuing requests to the API fixed the issue on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I had very same issue. But my case is just opposite to @dcod, where the development version of my app is http:// and hence I need to use http:// of maps.google.com.

I will update the behavior in the production where the app is going to be https://